# pagehandler not working the way it should

Tags: php

So I made a custom page handler to make my code much cleaner. I have it running on multiple websites but on the website I am working right now it doesn't work.

This is the code:

```
<?php
    $page = $_GET["p"];
    include_once("pages/" . $page . ".php");
    if($page == "") {
        header("Location: index.php?p=index");
    }
?>
```

> and this is the error:
>   Warning: include_once(): Failed opening 'pages/.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /home/ubuntu/workspace/admin_panel/page-handler.php on line 3
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/ubuntu/workspace/admin_panel/header.php:474) in /home/ubuntu/workspace/admin_panel/page-handler.php on line 5

It works on all of the other websites I have it running on.

Does someone know why it isn't working?
Thanks.

Comment: Seems like $_GET['p'] is empty. Also, you should be doing something to ensure the users can only reach the files you want them to. Perhaps create an array of valid pages, and check if $page is one of them.

Comment: @rjdown I know that's why I made an if statement. And about the files, it's not needed. Its all in a different server

Comment: `if(!empty($_GET["p"])){ $page = $_GET["p"]; (do stuff/include) }` - basically, your logic is off. You're checking if equal to `""` and trying to include before the GET is set.

Comment: But Rik you are trying to include the page BEFORE your if statement!

Comment: @rjdown Even if I inlude them after the if statement it doesn't work

Comment: and that header bit is caused by something else. Outputting before it somewhere.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Your answer worked for me, could you add is as an answer I don't want to take credit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As requested by the OP:

Comment to answer:

```
if(!empty($_GET["p"])){ 

   $page = $_GET["p"]; 

   // (do stuff/include) 

}
```

Basically, your logic is off. You're checking if equal to `""` and trying to include before the GET is set.

Check the following post also about the headers sent warning:

- [How to fix "Headers already sent" error in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php)

Plus, it is also best to add `exit;` after any header. Otherwise your code may want to continue to execute, should you have more below it.

Reference:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: @RikNijdeken I made an edit to the answer. You may want to reload it in order to see the additional information I've added.

Comment: @RikNijdeken You're welcome Rik, glad to have been of help, *cheers*